# I am not able to hide my p tags in javasctript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know where i am having an error but when i run this script it says undefined in firebug.Not telling me what is undefined.Here my javascript.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("p");
var length = elements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    elements[i].style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: i think yo are running it before the HTML loads. Try keeping your javascript code before </body>, also the function should be getElementsByTagName instead getElementsByName

Comment: I belivie it is `document.getElementsByTagName("p");` in the first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var length = elements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    elements[i].style.display='none';
}
```

`document.getElementsByName("p");` returns the elements that have a `name` attribute of `p` such as:

```
<span name="p"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `getElementsByTagName`

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var length = elements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    elements[i].style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct JS declaration to use would be

```
var elements = document.getElementByTagName("p")
```

rather than

```
var elements = document.getElementByName("p")
```

because the latter looks for any element with the value `p` for a name `(e.g. <img name="p" /> or <map name="p">)` rather than returning `<p>` elements.